# Converting HttpRequest to UnityWebRequest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httprequest, webgl, unitywebrequest

I want to build my project to WebGL and I need to use UnityWebRequest instead of HTTPWebRequest because System.Net namespaces is not supported on WebGL.

I am having issues converting the working HTTPRequest to a UnityWebRequest.

```
    /// Opens A Simple "webserver" On localhost:8080 For The Auth Redirect To Land On.
    private void StartLocalWebserver()
    {
        HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();

        httpListener.Prefixes.Add(twitchRedirectUrl);
        httpListener.Start();
        httpListener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(IncomingHttpRequest), httpListener);
    }


    /// Handles The Incoming HTTP Request
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    private void IncomingHttpRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        string code;
        string state;
        HttpListener httpListener;
        HttpListenerContext httpContext;
        HttpListenerRequest httpRequest;
        HttpListenerResponse httpResponse;
        string responseString;

        // Get Back The Reference To Our Http Listener
        httpListener = (HttpListener) result.AsyncState;

        // Fetch The Context Object
        httpContext = httpListener.EndGetContext(result);

        // The Context Object Has The Request Object For Us, That Holds Details About The Incoming Request
        httpRequest = httpContext.Request;

        code = httpRequest.QueryString.Get("code");
        state = httpRequest.QueryString.Get("state");

        // Check That We Got A Code Value And The State Value Matches Our Remembered One
        if ((code.Length > 0) && (state == _twitchAuthStateVerify))
        {
            // If All Checks Out, Use The Code To Exchange It For The Actual Auth Token At The API
            GetTokenFromCode(code);
            isAuthReady = true;
            UserID(_authToken);
        }

        // Build A Response To Send An "ok" Back To The Browser For The User To See
        httpResponse = httpContext.Response;
        responseString = "<html><body><b>DONE!</b><br>(You can close this tab/window now)</body></html>";
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

        // Send The Output To The Client Browser
        httpResponse.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
        System.IO.Stream output = httpResponse.OutputStream;
        output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        output.Close();

        // The HTTP Listener Has Served It's Purpose, Shut It Down
        httpListener.Stop();
    }
```

In these two methods I need to use UnityWebRequest instead of Http